# Do I need to use : when specifying a jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery

I have seen examples of

```
$(":input[type='text']").wijtextbox();
```

and also

```
$("input[type='text']").wijtextbox();
```

Do I need to use the ":". I'm familiar with the period and hash selectors but not the colon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`input` doesn't grab all the form objects like `select` and `textarea`, that's why they came out with `:input`

The `:input` selector basically selects all form controls.
http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Answer (score 4):

The `:input` is called **filter** selector because of `:` in front. It selects not only regular input types but also, `<textarea>`, `<select>`, etc

`input` only selects regular input types that start with `<input...`

[**:input**](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

> Description: Selects all **input**, **textarea**, **select** and **button** elements.